# Multi access array/list in thread-safe mode?

Tags: multithreading, list, delphi

has for some time that I'm trying to make sure this class with threads.
Unfortunately I can not understand where to act properly.

The problem:

The saving procedures take a long time, therefore I would like to use it in a dedicated thread. 
The idea is that every change in the root node, is increased the demand for saving if the thread saving is running. When the thread of saving ends if there are requests then resave still zeroing requests until there aren't requests.

But until I add nodes, there is no problem. At the moment, however, to remove a node (then all child nodes), if the thread saving is running, then creates rightly exceptions.

There is a solution or another way to save the root node at the same time making it editable. 
Obviously without duplicating the entire node for each saving request?

Thank you all.

Base Class:

```
interface

uses

  System.Classes, System.SysUtils;

type

  TNode<T> = class
  public type
    TNodeForEachProc = reference to procedure( const ANode: TNode<T>; var ABreak: Boolean );
    TNodeWriteProc = reference to procedure( const AWriter: TBinaryWriter; const AData: T );
    TNodeReadProc = reference to function( const AReader: TBinaryReader ): T;
    TNodeBufferedWriteProc = reference to procedure( const AWriter: TBufferedWriter; const AData: T );
    TNodeBufferedReadProc = reference to function( const AReader: TBufferedReader ): T;
    TNodeProgressProc = reference to procedure( const AIndex, ACount: Integer );
  private
    FCount: Integer;
    FCapacity: Integer;
    FNodes: TArray<TNode<T>>;
    {$IFDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}[Weak]{$ENDIF}FParent: TNode<T>;
    procedure Grow;
    procedure SetCapacity( const AValue: Integer );
    function Get( AIndex: Integer ): TNode<T>; inline;
    function GetIndex: Integer;
    function GetLevel: Integer;
    procedure Adopt( const ANode: TNode<T> );
    procedure Orphan;
    procedure SetParent( const AValue: TNode<T> );
  protected
    property Nodes:TArray<TNode<T>> read FNodes;
  public
    Data: T;
    constructor Create( const ACapacity: Integer = 0 ); overload;
    constructor Create( const ANode: TNode<T> ); overload;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Assign( const ANode: TNode<T> );
    function Add( const AData: T ): TNode<T>;
    procedure Clear; inline;
    function Count( const ARecursive: Boolean = False ): Integer; inline;
    function Empty: Boolean; inline;
    procedure Delete( const AIndex: Integer; const ACount: Integer = 1 );
    function ForEach( const AProc: TNodeForEachProc; const ARecursive: Boolean = True ): Boolean;
    property Index: Integer read GetIndex;
    property Node[ Index: Integer ]: TNode<T> read Get; default;
    property Level: Integer read GetLevel;
    property Parent: TNode<T> read FParent write SetParent;
    procedure SaveToStream( const AStream: TStream; const AWriterProc: TNodeWriteProc; const AProgressProc: TNodeProgressProc = nil );
    procedure LoadFromStream( const AStream: TStream; const AReaderProc: TNodeReadProc; const AProgressProc: TNodeProgressProc = nil );
    procedure SaveToFile( const AFileName: TFileName; const AWriterProc: TNodeBufferedWriteProc; const AProgressProc: TNodeProgressProc = nil );
    procedure LoadFromFile( const AFileName: TFileName; const AReaderProc: TNodeBufferedReadProc; const AProgressProc: TNodeProgressProc = nil );
  end;

implementation

{ TNode<T> }

constructor TNode<T>.Create( const ACapacity: Integer = 0 );
begin
  SetCapacity( ACapacity );
end;

constructor TNode<T>.Create( const ANode: TNode<T> );
begin
  Assign( ANode );
end;

destructor TNode<T>.Destroy;
begin
  Clear;
  Orphan;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TNode<T>.Assign( const ANode: TNode<T> );
var
  VIndex: Integer;
begin
  Clear;
  Data := ANode.Data;
  FCount := ANode.FCount;
  SetLength( FNodes, FCount );
  for VIndex := 0 to FCount - 1 do
  begin
    FNodes[ VIndex ] := TNode<T>.Create;
    FNodes[ VIndex ].Assign( ANode.FNodes[ VIndex ] );
  end;
end;

function TNode<T>.Add( const AData: T ): TNode<T>;
begin
  Result := TNode<T>.Create;
  Result.Data := AData;
  Adopt( Result );
end;

procedure TNode<T>.Clear;
begin
  Delete( 0, FCount );
  FNodes := nil;
  FCount := 0;
  FCapacity := 0;
end;

function TNode<T>.Count( const ARecursive: Boolean = False ): Integer;
var
  VCount: Integer;
begin
  if ARecursive then
  begin
    VCount := 0;
    ForEach(
      procedure( const Node: TNode<T>; var ABreak: Boolean )
      begin
        Inc( VCount );
      end
    );
    Result := VCount;
  end else
    Result := FCount;
end;

procedure TNode<T>.Delete( const AIndex: Integer; const ACount: Integer = 1 );
var
  VIndex: Integer;
begin
  for VIndex := AIndex to AIndex + ACount - 1 do
  begin
    FNodes[ VIndex ].FParent := nil;
    FNodes[ VIndex ].DisposeOf;
    Dec( FCount );
  end;
  System.Delete( FNodes, AIndex, ACount );
end;

function TNode<T>.Empty: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FCount = 0;
end;

function TNode<T>.ForEach( const AProc: TNodeForEachProc; const ARecursive: Boolean = True ): Boolean;
type
  TTypeNode = TNode<T>;
var
  VIndex: Integer;
  VTypeNode: TTypeNode;
  VBreak: Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  if Assigned( AProc ) then
    for VIndex := 0 to Count - 1 do
    begin
      VTypeNode := FNodes[ VIndex ];
      VBreak := False;
      AProc( VTypeNode, VBreak );
      if VBreak then
        Exit( False );
      if ARecursive then
        if not VTypeNode.ForEach( AProc ) then
          Exit( False );
    end;
end;

procedure TNode<T>.Grow;
var
  VDelta: Integer;
begin
  if FCapacity > 64 then
    VDelta := FCapacity div 4
  else
    if FCapacity > 8 then
      VDelta := 16
    else
      VDelta := 4;
  SetCapacity( FCapacity + VDelta );
end;

procedure TNode<T>.SetCapacity( const AValue: Integer );
begin
  if AValue > FCapacity then
  begin
    SetLength( FNodes, AValue );
    FCapacity := AValue;
  end;
end;

function TNode<T>.Get( AIndex: Integer ): TNode<T>;
begin
  Result := FNodes[ AIndex ];
end;

function TNode<T>.GetIndex: Integer;
var
  VIndex: Integer;
begin
  if FParent <> nil then
    for VIndex := 0 to FParent.Count - 1 do
      if FParent[ VIndex ] = Self then
        Exit( VIndex );
  Result := - 1;
end;

function TNode<T>.GetLevel: Integer;
begin
  if FParent = nil then
    Result := 0
  else
    Result := FParent.Level + 1;
end;

procedure TNode<T>.Adopt( const ANode: TNode<T> );
var
  VIndex: Integer;
begin
  ANode.FParent := Self;
  VIndex := FCount;
  if VIndex = FCapacity then
    Grow;
  FNodes[ VIndex ] := ANode;
  Inc( FCount );
end;

procedure TNode<T>.Orphan;
begin
  if FParent <> nil then
  begin
    System.Delete( FParent.FNodes, Index, 1 );
    Dec( FParent.FCount );
  end;
end;

procedure TNode<T>.SetParent( const AValue: TNode<T> );
begin
  if FParent <> AValue then
  begin
    Orphan;
    FParent := AValue;
    if FParent <> nil then
      FParent.Adopt( Self );
  end;
end;

procedure TNode<T>.SaveToStream( const AStream: TStream; const AWriterProc: TNodeWriteProc; const AProgressProc: TNodeProgressProc = nil );
var
  VCount: Integer;
  VIndex: Integer;
  VWriter: TBinaryWriter;
begin
  if Assigned( AWriterProc ) then
  begin
    VCount := Count( True );
    VIndex := 0;
    VWriter := TBinaryWriter.Create( AStream );
    try
      VWriter.Write( VCount );
      AWriterProc( VWriter, Data );
      VWriter.Write( Count );
      ForEach(
        procedure( const ANode: TNode<T>; var ABreak: Boolean )
        begin
          AWriterProc( VWriter, ANode.Data );
          VWriter.Write( ANode.Count );
          if Assigned( AProgressProc ) then
          begin
            AProgressProc( VIndex, VCount );
            Inc( VIndex );
          end;
        end
      );
    finally
      VWriter.DisposeOf;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TNode<T>.LoadFromStream( const AStream: TStream; const AReaderProc: TNodeReadProc; const AProgressProc: TNodeProgressProc = nil );
var
  VIndex: Integer;
  VCount: Integer;
  VReader: TBinaryReader;
  VCurrentNode: TNode<T>;
  VEntryNode: TNode<T>;
begin
  if Assigned( AReaderProc ) then
  begin
    Clear;
    VReader := TBinaryReader.Create( AStream );
    try
      VCount := VReader.ReadInteger;
      Data := AReaderProc( VReader );
      SetCapacity( VReader.ReadInteger );
      VCurrentNode := Self;
      for VIndex := 0 to VCount - 1 do
      begin
        VEntryNode := VCurrentNode.Add( AReaderProc( VReader ) );
        VEntryNode.SetCapacity( VReader.ReadInteger );
        if VEntryNode.FCapacity > 0 then
          VCurrentNode := VEntryNode
        else if VCurrentNode.FCount = VCurrentNode.FCapacity then
          if VCurrentNode.Parent <> nil then
          begin
            VCurrentNode := VCurrentNode.Parent;
            while ( VCurrentNode.FCount = VCurrentNode.FCapacity ) and ( VCurrentNode <> Self ) do
              if VCurrentNode.Parent = nil then
                VCurrentNode := Self
              else
                VCurrentNode := VCurrentNode.Parent;
          end else
            VCurrentNode := Self;
        if Assigned( AProgressProc ) then
          AProgressProc( VIndex, VCount );
      end;
    finally
      VReader.DisposeOf;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TNode<T>.SaveToFile( const AFileName: TFileName; const AWriterProc: TNodeBufferedWriteProc; const AProgressProc: TNodeProgressProc = nil );
var
  VCount: Integer;
  VIndex: Integer;
  VWriter: TBufferedWriter;
begin
  if Assigned( AWriterProc ) then
  begin
    VCount := Count( True );
    VIndex := 0;
    VWriter := TBufferedWriter.Create( AFileName );
    try
      VWriter.WriteInteger( VCount );
      AWriterProc( VWriter, Data );
      VWriter.WriteInteger( Count );
      if Assigned( AProgressProc ) then
      begin
        AProgressProc( VIndex, VCount );
        Inc( VIndex );
      end;
      ForEach(
        procedure( const ANode: TNode<T>; var ABreak: Boolean )
        begin
          AWriterProc( VWriter, ANode.Data );
          VWriter.WriteInteger( ANode.Count );
          if Assigned( AProgressProc ) then
          begin
            AProgressProc( VIndex, VCount );
            Inc( VIndex );
          end;
        end
      );
    finally
      VWriter.DisposeOf;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TNode<T>.LoadFromFile( const AFileName: TFileName; const AReaderProc: TNodeBufferedReadProc; const AProgressProc: TNodeProgressProc = nil );
var
  VIndex: Integer;
  VCount: Integer;
  VReader: TBufferedReader;
  VCurrentNode: TNode<T>;
  VEntryNode: TNode<T>;
begin
  if Assigned( AReaderProc ) then
  begin
    Clear;
    VReader := TBufferedReader.Create( AFileName );
    try
      VCount := VReader.ReadInteger;
      Data := AReaderProc( VReader );
      SetCapacity( VReader.ReadInteger );
      VCurrentNode := Self;
      for VIndex := 0 to VCount - 1 do
      begin
        VEntryNode := VCurrentNode.Add( AReaderProc( VReader ) );
        VEntryNode.SetCapacity( VReader.ReadInteger );
        if VEntryNode.FCapacity > 0 then
          VCurrentNode := VEntryNode
        else if VCurrentNode.FCount = VCurrentNode.FCapacity then
          if VCurrentNode.Parent <> nil then
          begin
            VCurrentNode := VCurrentNode.Parent;
            while ( VCurrentNode.FCount = VCurrentNode.FCapacity ) and ( VCurrentNode <> Self ) do
              if VCurrentNode.Parent = nil then
                VCurrentNode := Self
              else
                VCurrentNode := VCurrentNode.Parent;
          end else
            VCurrentNode := Self;
        if Assigned( AProgressProc ) then
          AProgressProc( VIndex, VCount );
      end;
    finally
      VReader.DisposeOf;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Hard to see how you can read the tree at the same time as modifying it. Why do you believe that is possible?

Comment: Thread safe is really simple if you interpolate the problem into a real world example. How can you drive with your car, when your wife is already using it? Buy another car (copy/clone) or wait until your wife has returned the car.

Comment: In this case you have to get a snapshot of the current state to save it within a thread. In the meantime it is safe to edit the original instance.

Comment: BTW: There is no need to `IFDEF` the `[weak]` attribute. It is only used if you compile for ARC platforms

Comment: Is for ARC platform. I'll try to buy me a new car! but the problem that on the phones memory has a high price!

Comment: He made believe this link: http://francois-piette.blogspot.it/2013/02/high-speed-generic-queue-class.html

Comment: You did not mention, that you have nodes containing a couple of MBs of data. If the snapshot data is really too big for memory, just store the snapshot on the disk and restore it for real persistence.

Comment: I thank you for the advice, but it's just to save on disk that takes my time, and I would not block the app while you're saving and give the user the opportunity to continue with the use of the app without having to pause for actions long.

Comment: 1. Take snapshot 2. Start persistence task with snapshot 3. Store snapshot to disk (thread) 4. Wait for database (thread) 5. Restore snapshot from disk (thread) 6. Persist snapshot in database (thread) - Where did you see any disturbance of the main thread? The blocking part is taking snapshot and starting the task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to add 'some' multithreading to your tree is to add TCriticalSection object to its root. The point is to ensure, that saving and editing are not happening simultaneously. So, when saving thread is executing, you can work with other objects in main thread (for example, GUI works all right), you can also gain access to this tree, but when you try to edit this tree when saving is not done, main thread will wait for all saving procedures to be complete.

I would point out that adding new nodes while saving thread is executing is potentially dangerous because it requires updating lists of nodes. At this moment reallocation of memory could happen (having bigger chunk at other place to contain all the elements) and saving thread accessing list at this very moment will fail dramatically!

There are possibilities to put critical section at every node of tree so our main thread will wait only if it modifies a node which is saved exactly at this moment, you can use TThreadList instead of TArray for storing list of nodes which will allow you to add new nodes while the old ones are still saving, but this way you get thousands of possibilities to shoot yourself in the leg, only with extreme caution it will work as it should

So I think, you should start with one critical section and see if it is fast enough for your needs.

Comment: Serialization is hardly going to help parallel execution speed. Per node locks? Easy to say, but what's the implementation? Parallel tree data structures are non trivial. You can't just say, "use locks" and call it a day.

Comment: If I understood question correctly, user works with data, then saves them to disc and should continue work while saving thread is executed. (I still can't get used that pressing enter posts comment already, sorry). The simplest solution - 'making our data read-only while saving in progress' is already much improvement over single-threaded application: GUI doesn't freeze, and user can navigate through document, and often these some seconds while user gets back to work is enough for thread to finish work. Even if not (and we show saving progress bar), it's better then total freeze of application

Comment: In reality, the synchronization is not in itself a problem. I have already attempted to block the nodes being saved. The problem is that being a tree on I have not found so that the parent block to level the root node. That means that the 1000 level can potentially block multiple nodes 100,000 going up to level 2! I apologize if I was not clear!

Comment: Thx  Yuriy, I think your solution is the simplest, and that does not change much from mine. Surely, as I have already planned the progress bar, i will implements a read-only in the case is still saving. Or maybe they will consider the possibility to lock the first-level nodes, as they often represent major categories. Thanks again. Certainly not a perfect solution but approaches

Answer (score 0):

Finally, thanks to your suggestions, here is the best I could do.
Unfortunately, slow, and with the double memory usage in the saving step.

Time on mobile phones are considered x500 and for the saving step x1000 :(

Tested in Interl I7 with 1.000.000 of short string: "Item Index XXX.XXX"

Thanks all.

[image]

Some log:

...

ForEach ( 1000000 ) in 1719 ms

Deleting ( 1000000 ) in 1250 ms

Saving File ( 940150 ) in 3078 ms

Adding ( 1000000 ) in 1828 ms

ForEach ( 1000000 ) in 1094 ms

Adding ( 1000000 ) in 1219 ms

Deleting ( 970781 ) in 1406 ms

ForEach ( 970781 ) in 1625 ms

Adding ( 1000000 ) in 1703 ms

Deleting ( 1000000 ) in 531 ms

Saving File ( 1000000 ) in 3625 ms

ForEach ( 1000000 ) in 813 ms

Adding ( 1000000 ) in 1016 ms

...

Simple class:

```
  TThreadSafeNode<T> = class
  private
    FNode: TNode<T>;
    FCriticalSection: TCriticalSection;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Lock: TNode<T>;
    procedure Unlock;
  end;
```

And testing threads:

```
var
  VThreadSafeNode: TThreadSafeNode<String>;
begin

  Randomize;

  VThreadSafeNode := TThreadSafeNode<String>.Create;

  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    var
      VIndex: Integer;
      VCount: Integer;
      VTickCount: Cardinal;
      VRoot: TNode<String>;
    begin
      while True do
      begin

        VTickCount := TThread.GetTickCount;

        VRoot := VThreadSafeNode.Lock;
        try

          VRoot.Clear;

          VRoot.Capacity := Nodes;
          for VIndex := 1 to Nodes do
          begin
            VRoot.Add( 'Item Index ' + VIndex.ToString );
          end;

          VCount := VRoot.Count( True );

        finally
          VThreadSafeNode.Unlock;
        end;

        TThread.Synchronize(
          nil,
          procedure
          begin
            Memo1.Lines.Add( 'Adding ( ' + VCount.ToString + ' ) in ' + ( TThread.GetTickCount - VTickCount ).ToString + ' ms' );
          end
        );
      end;
    end
  ).Start;

  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    var
      VIndex: Integer;
      VCount: Integer;
      VTickCount: Cardinal;
      VRoot: TNode<String>;
    begin
      while True do
      begin
        VTickCount := TThread.GetTickCount;

        VRoot := VThreadSafeNode.Lock;
        try

          VIndex := Random( VRoot.Count );
          VRoot.Delete( VIndex, Random( VRoot.Count ) - VIndex );

          VCount := VRoot.Count( True );

        finally
          VThreadSafeNode.Unlock;
        end;

        TThread.Synchronize(
          nil,
          procedure
          begin
            Memo1.Lines.Add( 'Deleting ( ' + VCount.ToString + ' ) in ' + ( TThread.GetTickCount - VTickCount ).ToString + ' ms' );
          end
        );

        TThread.Sleep( Random( 1000 ) );
      end;
    end
  ).Start;

  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    var
      VCount: Integer;
      VTickCount: Cardinal;
      VRoot: TNode<String>;
    begin
      while True do
      begin
        VTickCount := TThread.GetTickCount;

        VRoot := VThreadSafeNode.Lock;
        try

          VRoot.ForEach(
            procedure( const Item: TNode<String>; var ABreak: Boolean )
            begin
              Item.Value := Item.Value;
            end
          );

          VCount := VRoot.Count( True );

        finally
          VThreadSafeNode.Unlock;
        end;

        TThread.Synchronize(
          nil,
          procedure
          begin
            Memo1.Lines.Add( 'ForEach ( ' + VCount.ToString + ' ) in ' + ( TThread.GetTickCount - VTickCount ).ToString + ' ms' );
          end
        );

        TThread.Sleep( Random( 1000 ) );
      end;
    end
  ).Start;

  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    var
      VCount: Integer;
      VLastPercent: Integer;
      VTickCount: Cardinal;
      VRoot: TNode<String>;
    begin
      while True do
      begin
        VTickCount := TThread.GetTickCount;

        VLastPercent := 0;

        VRoot := TNode<String>.Create;
        try
          VRoot.Assign( VThreadSafeNode.Lock );
        finally
          VThreadSafeNode.Unlock;
        end;

        try

          VRoot.SaveToFile(
            TPath.Combine( TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath, 'test.txt' ),
            procedure( const AWriter: TBufferedWriter; const AData: String )
            begin
              AWriter.WriteString( AData );
            end,
            procedure( const AIndex, ACount: Integer )
            var
              VPercent: Integer;
            begin
              VPercent := Trunc( ( ( AIndex + 1 ) * 100 ) / ACount );
              if VLastPercent <> VPercent then
              begin
                VLastPercent := VPercent;
                TThread.Synchronize(
                  nil,
                  procedure
                  begin
                    ProgressBar1.Value := VLastPercent;
                  end
                );
              end;
            end
          );

          VCount := VRoot.Count( True );

        finally
          VRoot.DisposeOf;
        end;

        TThread.Synchronize(
          nil,
          procedure
          begin
            Memo1.Lines.Add( 'Saving File ( ' + VCount.ToString + ' ) in ' + ( TThread.GetTickCount - VTickCount ).ToString + ' ms' );
          end
        );

        TThread.Sleep( Random( 1000 ) );
      end;
    end
  ).Start;

end;
```

Comment: I see that you have several threads which read a tree. In that case TCriticalSection is too severe, you can use TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer, it will allow more than one threads to read data simultaneously.

I see that you add one million nodes - will it be the case at the real work? What do you do exactly, if it's not a secret?

Slow saving is bad even if it works in background. Say, user saves data and closes the program. You could just close the window and still run background thread, lot of programs do so, but that's evil! User may want to turn of device and either lose his data,

Comment: or device won't turn off waiting for your thread to finish, it may seem like hanging and user will make hard turn off. Another case: user wants to copy data to other place: flash drive, sd card and so on. But saving thread is not finished, so user will copy uncomplete data, which won't work. You should not close program window until all data is saved, and if saving is slow, we have a problem.  Maybe you could use file hierarchy instead of 1 file, so each file corresponds to each node, etc? But without details I don't know what's best in your case.

Comment: Thx for help, of course app before closing will wait and prompt message/progessbar to user. The data are encrypted so i can't spleat, the result is same. 1.000.000 are more in real case i think 20.000 are more correct but with real long string data.
On my mobile Galaxy S5 i saving 70.000 around in 3/4 sec.